# Importing packages from linux ISO

Tags: ubuntu, puppy-linux

I have ISO of Puppy Linux and just now I have downloaded ISO for Ubuntu.

Puppy Linux does not have gcc installed . But I know Ubuntu 14 has gcc and many other softwares installed. So **Can I import those packages(like gcc, etc) from ISO file of Ubuntu and install it in puppy Linux or vice versa ??**

I have slow internet connection and its pain to download all those packages again. I have many programmes installed in Puppy Linux too . So I don't want to leave Puppy Linux and redownload programmes again in Ubuntu. If its possible to migrate from Ubuntu to Puppy or Puppy to Ubuntu offline, please

P.S. I copied whole / of puppy Linux to Ubuntu's / thinking that it would work. Before restarting it worked, but after I rebooted Ubuntu, it stopped loading :p ..

Comment: maybe you can have a ubuntu installation in some chroot .

Comment: even mixing ubuntu with debian is very very dangerous , and puppy is far less similar to ubuntu than debian .

Comment: there are some sayings that the puppy package manager accepts deb , but i don't find more documentation supporting those sayings . have you already read some manuals ? what do the manuals say ?

Comment: Yep, Puppy Linux supports deb packages. Basically importing deb from Ubuntu may work .. Is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

> I know Ubuntu 14 has gcc and many other softwares installed.

Actually I would guess the live CD/install .iso *does not* include `gcc`, but it might.  That image is just intended to get you a minimal desktop system.  Anything you want after that needs to be installed via network.

*[In fact, as the OP observes in a comment, there is a way to rip packages from the live CD by using `dpkg-repack`.]*

If you downloaded all the packages available for Ubuntu 14, they might fill a dozen or more DVDs.  Not one CD.  So...

> its pain to download all those packages *again.*

If it was not installed, then they were not part of the .iso, so you did not download them in the first place.

> Puppy Linux does not have gcc installed

But presumably Puppy has its own package manager and you can install gcc that way.  You probably cannot use the one from Ubuntu, and vice versa.

> I copied whole / of puppy Linux to Ubuntu's / thinking that it would work.

That was a very bad idea.  You might as well start from scratch with that partition now, it will be thoroughly wrecked.

Comment: i come to guess that puppy is totally a livecd distro . i don't seem to find any repositories on the homepage .

Comment: Puppy linux supports deb and Ubuntu and Puppy are both "linux" so ,  maybe gcc from ubuntu works in puppy linux too.. Using pupy linux package manager to install gcc would cost me more Internet Data (which i have limited) . I have heard there is a way to import packages in Ubuntu as a .deb file for offline installation. so that may work,, Thats why i was asking :)

Comment: There is a way to download `.deb` packages and install them later.  The reason you didn't get an answer about that is because you asked about installing packages "from ISO".  Anyway, it's not necessarily impossible to run stuff compiled by one distro on another, it's just not guaranteed either, and *may* cause unforeseen complications.  You'd have to assess it on a case by case basis.  Gcc might be fine...

Comment: I have done it :) .. from ubuntu live cd , i imported all the packages as a .deb using dpkg-repack tool.. Although it was pain to do installation one by one. It took me couple of hours. :D :D

Comment: You should (try and) add that as an answer then in case someone is looking to do the same thing. :)  It might not let you because of the ["privellege system"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) though. :(